# Using MPU6050 with ESP32 Cam- MPU Not Detected

Tags: i2c, esp32, mpu6050, error

Hi I'm trying to build a self balancing robot using my esp32 cam, but so far I haven't been able to setup my mpu6050 with it.I'm using the adafruit libraries with the given example sketches.
The only thing I've done different is using two different SDA , SCL pins. So to get that done in the software I have made the following change to the Adafruit_I2CDevice.cpp file, where the TwoWire.begin() happens.

[image: EDIT]

This is the tutorial I'm following, [Click Here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-i2c-communication-arduino-ide/#3)

So Far this is What the Serial Monitor shows me

```
Adafruit MPU6050 test!
Failed to find MPU6050 chip
```

Any help to get my ESP32 to work with the MPU6050 is highly appreciated.

Also note I managed to read the bare values from the MPU using only the Wire.h library.The reson I want to use the Adafruit library is because it makes use of the DMP on the MPU6050.